# USB 3 not working in SuperSpeed mode

Tags: windows-10, usb-3

I have a problem with my USB 3.0 ports. I bought a new USB Wi-fi card which requires USB 3 port to get full connection speed. However, when I connect it to USB 3 port, they do not enter SuperSpeed mode, they act as if they were USB 2.0. I have tried everything - updating BIOS, changing BIOS settings, reinstalling drivers, plugging devices faster etc. USBTreeview shows [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/148ak.png) SuperSpeed ports are available, however I cannot connect anything to them. Can someone tell me what else is there to do? I have a MSI B250M PRO-VD motherboard and I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Model of usb wifi card?

Comment: Lanberg NC1200 WI

Comment: "Transmission speed: up to 1167 Mb/s in total,">>>>https://lanberg.pl/en/produkt/NC-1200-WI

Comment: Yes, and I get only 160 Mbps. My ISP gives me 600 Mbps. Where is the remaining 440 Mbps?

Comment: Its the USB Lanberg NC1200 WI device limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. It turned out that the Lanberg device was broken. I used another and it properly connected to the USB 3 port. Topic closed.